# conda: create env with newest package

Tags: python, conda

I would like conda to install the latest subversion of python in the new environment as in

```
conda create -n envname python==3.6.x
```

where x is the latest sub-version.

Just found that I can do `conda search python` to find all available python versions and manually enter the one that I prefer.

But is there an automated way to do this with something like:

```
conda create -n envname python==3.6.x  # or
conda create -n envname python==3.6.*  # or
conda create -n envname python==3.6.^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conda create -n envname 'python>=3.6,<3.7'`

This worked for me. It installs the latest version of python above 3.6 but below 3.7.